# Removing object from array; how to avoid nulls

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I have an array that is a object which I carry in session `lifeFleetSelectedTrucksList`
I also have objects of class `fleetUnit`

```
class fleetUnit {
    public $idgps_unit = null;
    public $serial = null;
}

class lifeFleetSelectedTrucksList {
    public $arrayList = array();
}

$listOfTrucks = new lifeFleetSelectedTrucksList(); //this is the array that I carry in session
if (!isset($_SESSION['lifeFleetSelectedTrucksList'])) {
    $_SESSION['lifeFleetSelectedTrucksList'] == null; //null the session and add new list to it.
} else {
    $listOfTrucks = $_SESSION['lifeFleetSelectedTrucksList'];
}
```

I use this to remove element from array:

```
$listOfTrucks = removeElement($listOfTrucks, $serial);
```

And this is my function that removes the element and returns the array without the element:

```
function removeElement($listOfTrucks, $remove) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($listOfTrucks->arrayList); $i++) {
        $unit = new fleetUnit();
        $unit = $listOfTrucks->arrayList[$i];
        if ($unit->serial == $remove) {
            unset($listOfTrucks->arrayList[$i]);
            break;
        } elseif ($unit->serial == '') {
            unset($listOfTrucks->arrayList[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $listOfTrucks;
}
```

Well, it works- element gets removed, but I have array that has bunch of null vaues instead. How do I return the array that contains no null elements? Seems that I am not suing something right.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you mean is that the array keys are not continuous anymore. An array does not have "null values" in PHP, unless you set a value to `null`.

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
// array(0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar', 2 => 'baz');

unset($array[1]);

// array(0 => 'foo', 2 => 'baz');
```

Two approaches to this:

1. Loop over the array using `foreach`, not a "manual" `for` loop, then it won't matter what the keys are.
2. Reset the keys with [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values).

Also, removing trucks from the list should really be a method of `$listOfTrucks`, like `$listOfTrucks->remove($remove)`. You're already using objects, use them to their full potential!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
<?php

$entry = array(
         0 => 'foo',
         1 => false,
         2 => -1,
         3 => null,
         4 => ''
      );

print_r(array_filter($entry));
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
[0] => foo
[2] => -1
)
```

Comment: Well, is this normal? Should `unset` leave nulls behind?

Comment: Nope, It should not give null with arrays.